# Sitecore WFFM: CacheOutputDuration

Tags: sitecore

Sitecore WebForms for Marketers:

Can anyone tell me in which assembly and class this setting is being used?

```
<setting name="WFM.Mvc.CacheOutputDuration" value="60" />
```

Found in Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.config.

I have been searching through the Sitecore Forms assemblies using dotPeek, but no luck.

Version 2.4 rev.141008.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be used by constructor of the Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Attributes.Filters.CacheOutputAttribute class (Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.dll assembly)

Thank you Sitecore Support.